# Problem having seamless texture on mesh

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm making a piece of armor to use a game in a game engine and I've been generating by own custom seamless textures to come up with a pattern. I'm trying to create a gambeson, and thus I need a quilted like pattern very much like this:

[image]

However, no matter how I unwrap my model, I'm constantly getting seams or the UV's just seem to stretch for some reason. I've also tried using UV Squares addon but that doesn't seem to help much either.

Here are some of the problems:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Can someone tell me what it is I'm doing wrong? I just can't seem to figure it out.

Blend file:

[image]

Comment: I have made a start but ......... now other things to do this evening. Check in again tomorrow and I should have an answer for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seams are a very real part of most clothing items.

The main thing wrong with your UV's is their alignment.

Basically you need to add seams where they would be on a similar real world piece of clothing. I added vertical seam from under the armpits to the waist.

[image]

Unwrap and rotate the UV islands so that they are correctly aligned with the texture. Then straighten (align to X to Y) edges where ever it makes sense to do so. Pin these straightened <kbd>P</kbd> edges, so they don't move and Unwrap a second time.

[image]

The rest is tweaking here and there, with one eye in the 3D editor to see if it is an improvement or not.
To check for stretching sometimes it helps to switch to have a UV grid on the model. Other times (but I find a little less useful), is to enable the Stretching Overlay in the UV Editor.

[image]

To re leave some of the stretching in the original sleeves unwrap I added a seam close to the top of the arm then unwrapped a second time. Moved the two islands close together then tweaked the vertices along the seam to align the up together again then used the **Weld** tool (UV Editor) to weld the two edges back together again.

The result is not perfect by any means...  more time and more tweaking :)

[image]

Doing this has reminded me about the **UV Magic** addon that ships with Blender. I haven't used it yet but there appears to be some very useful tools included. Checkout the **UV Sculpt** tool, illustrated in this Video at 8:20  https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=533&v=BKZX3Xac7X4&feature=emb_logo )

Blend file [image]

Comment: Oh, man, such a thorough answer! Let me just bookmark this for future reference...

Comment: :) ..........for the next time you have need to create a gambeson model ? lol

Comment: Well, some fashion trends never fade away :). [Shad](https://youtu.be/ODS7ksbBRuE) would be proud.

Comment: Thanks to Shad I think I can now consider myself a world authority on medieval Gambesons.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I was able to fix all my UV problems!