# How does one make a straight grid from a UV unwrap?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm somewhat new to blender. How exactly does one stretch UV islands so that they form a perfect grid? I'm looking to scale/rotate islands from two points, sort of like unfolding a beach towel. I'd like to do this to more easily texture my model.

I've tried to illustrate an example below:

[image: Image of my current UV map, for visibility.]

Thank you!

Comment: Hello and welcome :). There is an addon called UV Squares, which does exactly that. https://github.com/Radivarig/UvSquares

Comment: In the UV Editor the RMB will open a context menu. There you will find some tools for straightening edges. Can I point you to this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165354/problem-having-seamless-texture-on-mesh/165572#165572. Also the top two and the one in the middle right UV islands need more seams marked before unwrapping. Other than that R to rotate and S to scale is the same as in the 3D editor.

Comment: .......... and welcome to the Blender Stack Exchange :)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78358/how-to-straighten-curved-uvs-into-straight-belt/78376#78376 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74041/how-to-perfectly-align-uv-coordinates-automatically/74045#74045 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56748/help-with-smart-uv/56766#56766